# Is UNCACHE table a lazy operation in Spark SQL?

Tags: apache-spark, caching, apache-spark-sql

The Apache Spark SQL operation [CACHE table](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/language-manual/cache-table.html) has an option so that it runs lazy.
But what about UNCACHE table ? The [documentation](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/language-manual/uncache-table.html) doesn't say anything if it is lazy or not. Will the table be dropped immediately from cache or will it be deferred until the next run of the garbage collection? If it is lazy, is there a way to find out, if my table is still cached or not?

Comment: For question 2, `spark.catalog.listTables.show`

Comment: just try it out and look into the "storage" tab in Spark UI

Comment: @RaphaelRoth I prefer a solution, which can be coded.

Comment: @asmaier did you get to the bottom of this :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default UNCACHE operation is non-blocking. If you use the DSL, you can call `df.unpersist(true)` on a dataframe/dataset to make the operation blocking.

Comment: So the API of CACHE and UNCACHE is somewhat inconsistent, because by default CACHE is blocking.

Comment: Not 100% certain about the SparkSQL implementation of `CACHE` but in the DSL I have observed `cache()` operations that behave as actions (do work immediately) and ones that behave as transformations (return immediately and the actual caching will happen during the execution of an action). I have not dived into the source code to determine what causes the difference in behavior. Likely it is the extent to which some of the partitions are already loaded.